# submit PUT request through CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-cloudfront

Can anyone please help me before I go crazy?

I have been searching for any documentation/sample-code (in JavaScript) for uploading files to S3 via CloudFront but I can't find a proper guide.

I know I could use Tranfer Acceleration feature for faster uploads and yeah, Transfer Acceleration essentially does the job through CloudFront Edge Points but as long as I searched, it is possible to make the POST/PUT request via AWS.CloudFront...

Also read an article posted in 2013 says that AWS just added a functionality to make POST/PUT requests but says not a single thing about how to do it!?

CloudFront documentation for JavaScript sucks, it does not even show any sample codes. All they do is assuming that we already know all the things about the subject. If I knew, why would I dive into documentation in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is some confusion here about adding these requests. This feature was added simply to allow POST/PUT requests to be supported for your origin so that functionality in your application such as form submissions or API requests would now function.

The recommended approach as you pointed out is to make use of S3 transfer acceleration, which actually makes use of the CloudFront edge locations.

> Transfer Acceleration takes advantage of Amazon CloudFront’s globally distributed edge locations. As the data arrives at an edge location, data is routed to Amazon S3 over an optimized network path.

Comment: Thank you Chris! After reading tens of articles/docs about CloudFront,  it gave me the idea of making POST/PUT requests straight through AWS.CloudFront. Now I can make sure that there is only one way to upload files to S3 faster which is via Transfer Acceleration. I would like to give you +1 but since I am new, app does not let me do it

Comment: No problem, you can always com back when you can. Glad I could help :)

Comment: After couple decades of research, I found out that it is possible to make PUT/POST request through CloudFront. Official AWS FAQ says; It's recommended to use CF over TA if throughput doesn't exceed 1GB. Since users won't be uploading files larger than 100MB, CF is what I should go with. Also, I've read about people complaining latency issues with TA uploads. The only thing I couldn't figure out is how to implement uploading files with CloudFront PUT/POST request. I am using JavaScript and I can't find any sample code or anything. Can you guide me please?

Comment: Right taken a look, you want to look at examples for S3 uploads and replace the domain with the cloud front distribution domain. That should give you direction to start looking at (pretty sure you can’t used SDK instead you’ll need to construct request). Hope this helps for some direction :)